# Selenium RC testing with Google Map API

Tags: java, google-maps, selenium, junit

I am currently testing a site: http://www.paperminer.org.au/
Google Map API exists, and it will generate markers in different position. I would like to click on one of these markers but I am not sure on how to do this.

I'm using Selenium RC/Junit 4 Testing Framework in UNIX environment to test. The site itself is mainly built in Javascript/Jquery. Additionally, I use Selenium IDE to record the steps and format it to Selenium RC/Junit 4.

Recording each steps only produce google map canvas and are not clickable:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='map-canvas']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/canvas</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=loc-pb40359</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried SikuliFirefoxDriver, but there seems to be problem dealing in UNIX environment.
I am currently looking at the clickAt function but I can't seem to figure out the coordstring.

Anyone have any solution?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should try the sikuli using its java jar instead of sikulidriver. Sikuli gives more options... http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

Comment: I was actually working with that previously. I encountered problems within my environment. I was attempting the Hello World just like the tutorial, but I still have problems. Eventhough I have g++ and openCV installed on my ubuntu, for some reason it wont compile. see https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/235765 for further details